# Converting a hex value to byte with 8 digits in C#

Tags: c#

I receive a value of "7". Using my code below. I get "111" but what I need is "0000111" and if I receive "255" I get "1001010101" but what I need to get is "11111111". Please see my code below:

```
_dataRx = ((SerialPort) (sender)).ReadLine();
_dataRx = _dataRx.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
var x = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(_dataRx, 16), 2);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

I need to have 8 digits always since I need to place it in an array.
Can you please help. Thank you.

Comment: Where should I place it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you want to treat `_dataRx` (say, `"255"`) as a *decimal*, not **hexa**decimal value (`0x255 == 597 == 1001010101 (binary)` when `255 == 0xFF = 11111111 (binary)` required):

```
string x = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(_dataRx), 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can get it to be the way I need it to be? The "7" as "000111" and the 255 as "11111111"? I am trying to place it into an array where I can get the value of 1 as On and 0 as Off by getting the index of an array.

Comment: Use PadLeft(8, '0')

Comment: So sorry Dmitry. Your solution is absolutely right.Thank you!